# Redirect specific url to another folder in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two directories in my hosting: **DIR1** and **DIR2**.

In the htaccess file I have redirected domain.com on DIR1.

*RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ [NC]*

*RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/DIR1/*

*RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /DIR1/$1 [L]

My problem:

I have a specific url: domain.com/aaa/bbb/files

I want to display content from **DIR2** after opening this address

Comment: which file in DIR2 you want to access when you enter the url domain.com/aaa/bbb/files?

Comment: Maybe I will explain it again.

On my hosting in the /public_html/ directory I have two subdirectories DIR1, DIR2 (DIR1 and DIR are on the same level) and htaccess file. 

Domena.com is redirected to DIR1. All pages for domain.com come from DIR1

However, I have one specific URL. e.g. domain.com/aaa/bbb/files

I want the DIR2 content to display at this URL

Answer (score 0):

Add a `RewriteRule` only for that file:

```
RewriteRule ^(aaa/bbb/files)$ /DIR2/$1 [L]
```

Comment: where you file located? and which url you requested?

Comment: I don’t know how to describe this problem differently.

I have:

/public_html/dir1
/public_html/dir2
/public_html/.htaccess

domain.com is redirect to dir1 in .htaccesss. This directory contains my CMS. It works ok.

I need a specific url at doemna.com. e.g. domena.com/something/something/dir2

DIR2 contains a completely different php script. I need to run this script at this address. Without changing the url.